# kendodatetimepicker selects wrong date

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

when I set the Minimum date as Today for Kendo UI DateTimePicker and when I select the current  date from the calendar it selects the wrong date(when selected 06/05/2013 it displays as 07/05/2013).check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n6GtT/12/

```
 var start = $("#start").kendoDateTimePicker({
                    //value: today,
                    max:today,
                    change: startChange,
                    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy"]
                }).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

                var end = $("#end").kendoDateTimePicker({
                    //value: today,
                    min:today,
                    change: endChange,
                    parseFormats: ["MM/dd/yyyy"]
                }).data("kendoDateTimePicker");

                start.max(end.value());
                end.min(start.value());
            });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the today variable that you are setting. By removing the formatting of today's date you get the expected behavior.

Here is the [**updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n6GtT/15/).

So this:

```
var today = new Date(kendo.format('{0:MM-dd-yyyy}', new Date()));
```

Becomes:

```
var today = new Date();
```

This most likely has to do with Kendo parsing the date twice. Once in the kendo.format() and once in the kendoDatePicker.

Months in JavaScript are zero based and need to be incremented to reflect the correct date.

Comment: Thanks!Still I see the same issue.I found that the issue is  with months that has 30 days.When the month has only 30 days it displays next month.

Comment: You are still seeing the same issue even in the updated fiddle? I just double checked and it is working fine for months with 30 days.

Comment: I removed the formatting of today's date and still was able to reproduce the issue.Check this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n6GtT/45/

Comment: When I selected the current date that is set as minimum date I see this issue. When I go back and select some other date I don't see this issue(select the date 06/05/2013,it displays as 07/05/2013)